# How PWA can be useful rather than developing a Simple web Application

Tags: web, progressive-web-apps

I know I am very bad at asking a question so please tell me rather than downvote me...thanx

Q1: How Is Progressive Web Application Useful?

Q2: What Type of Application Should be Built using PWA is there any Specific Application which contains a lot of CPU utilization or Simple Static Pages with just small interaction with Server?

Q3: What should be the Application Architecture? In General?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are a lot of reason for using PWA rather than web-apps or native applications.

**A1**:To answer your first question there are some articles found on internet, here I recommend some of them to read:

- [Google Developers PWA documentation](https://developers.google.com/web/progressive-web-apps/)
- [What is PWA?](https://blog.bitsrc.io/what-is-a-pwa-and-why-should-you-care-388afb6c0bad)
- [Important tips about PWA](https://medium.com/@deepusnath/4-points-to-keep-in-mind-before-introducing-progressive-web-apps-pwa-to-your-team-8dc66bcf6011)

**A2**: There are no limitation and restriction on app you wanna develop. (Also you should pay attention to the key things like caching, which are considerable and important in native/web apps, too.)

**A3**: The architecture is very similar to web-apps except it **must** have some additional files:

1. [manifest.json](https://developers.google.com/web/fundamentals/web-app-manifest/) (Which is used to declare something like application name, the icons and etc. and it must be placed in the root of the project)
2. [serviceWorker.js](https://developers.google.com/web/fundamentals/primers/service-workers/) (Which gives you additional features like push notification, background works and etc.)

**NOTE**: As it obvious your Progressive Web App should be responsive to support different resolution of mobile screens.

Comment: this is so far the very good answer, i appreciate everyone efforts

Answer (score 1):

PWA is not a single technology or a framework , set of features in web which helps to improve your application progressively. 
 It means if you have a modern browser you will get an awesome user experience else those features just not support it , your application will have existing features remains as it is.

Let's talk about what all the features we can use to enhance our existing or new web application .

- You can bring native look and feel of mobile device apps on your web
  pages. It's not the responsiveness of web page but you can access the
  native features such as camera , accessing geo location, push
  notifications.
- Offline Capability when your internet connection get lost through caching.
- Background Synchronization of data
- Icon on the home screen , you don't need to install the application
  from the app store to place it on your home screen.

There are three import things I want to summarize about the progressive web application.

**Reliable** : Application will load instantly even in a uncertain condition and provide offline functionality through caching.
https://developers.google.com/web/progressive-web-apps/#reliable

**Fast** : Respond quickly as possible based on the user interactions.
https://developers.google.com/web/progressive-web-apps/#fast

**Engaging** : Feels like a native app on mobile devices.
https://developers.google.com/web/progressive-web-apps/#engaging

Answer (score 0):

Q1: Progressive web applications (particularly the service worker part of them) are useful because they can (a) be very fast and (b) work offline. Using a service worker to cache resources (HTML, JS, CSS) on the user's device can create almost instant page-load times on subsequent visits to your site. In addition, this can make your site available even without a network connection. Progressive web apps (with a manifest file) can also be installed on the device home screen, making them easily accessible, like native apps.

I'm not sure I understand Q2 and Q3, so I'll leave those for someone else to answer.

Comment: looks great, like we are getting away from native development